# Why is my VPython program running so slowly on this glowscript IDE?

Tags: python-2.7, vpython, glowscript

so I'm currently struggling with figuring out why my VPython program runs so slowly. I worked on this with others a few months ago, and it was working perfectly fine then, but opening it now, the program became super buggy!

http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/cs5squad/folder/Public/program/Sep

I thought that maybe it was glowscript/VPython itself, but I looked at previous drafts of this project I did, and it was working perfectly.

http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/cs5squad/folder/Public/program/notlaggy

I worked on this project with someone else, and so I'm thinking that person may have added one line of code or something to make it work so slowly. I'm not a particular expert at VPython, so I'm a little lost as to what I can do to fix this.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too many stars. Try changing

def star_maker():
    """Generates random stars."""
    for x in range(10000):

to

def star_maker():
    """Generates random stars."""
    for x in range(1000):

It seems to run smoother.

Comment: This helped! Thank you!!